# add path in linux and related command

Tags: linux, path

I tried to add the path in the remote computer by using this command:
PATH="$PATH:/new/path";export PATH

and after add the path I used the numactl command and I found this message;
numactl: execution of `fiscof2': No such file or directory

what is that mean?

Comment: After you've altered your path, is which able to find `fiscof2`? (`which "fiscof2"`)?

Comment: fiscof2 is the code that I am try to run it by using numactl

Comment: I have no experience with `numactl`, but the standard error message you're receiving makes me think that `numactl /path/dir/to/fiscof2` may solve your problem. Changing values for `$PATH` only change where to look for executable programs, NOT for input files (which I'm assuming `fiscof2` is). Good luck